# Alignment issue in the previous year's Winter Bash site's top bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar, winter-bash

There is an alignment issue in the previous year's Winter Bash site's top bar. The tool tip texts are displayed next to its DIV.

For example, when trying to access the following Winter Bash sites, I can see the alignment issue:

https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com

https://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Top bar]

When highlight the page, the badges related tool tip texts are displayed.

> [image: Top bar when highlights]

Received the following error in the browser console:

> [image: Console]

The error message in plain text as:

> ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
>       `<anonymous>` https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/18/winter-bash-2017:646

Comment: This is happening for me too!